# Maven retrieves not expected jar

Tags: java, maven, log4j, log4j2

I have `Java` `Maven` project in `Eclipse` IDE. I'm planning to use `log4j2` in my project. For this reason I put dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
```

Maven has retrieved single jar file `log4j-1.2.12.jar`. Looks like it is even not `log4j2`, but `log4j` library.

For not maven project I have downloaded two jar's - `log4j-api-2.6.1.jar` and `log4j-core-2.6.1.jar`

How to understand this discrepancy?

Comment: Check parent pom's etc..could be used as transitive dependencies...

Comment: I'm terribly sorry but this is your 7th Maven beginner's question in 2 days. Have you read any documentation, tutorial or searched the web or SO before?

Answer (score 0):

I see the right version jar's are downloaded. Where do you see the jar's have you mentioned? Did you try to update project?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks I did mistake - log4j2 is also downloaded. But why maven downloads older version of log4 too when I do update project?

Comment: Not sure, where are you looking at, sharing screenshots would help to understand the problem. how does your pom.xml looks like?

Comment: @vico Perform `mvn dependency:tree` on your project to see where the older version comes from (most probably as a transitive dependency from some other dependency).